# How to programatically get the UI Hierarchy in my automation script?

Tags: javascript, instruments, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I tried to store the result of target.logElementTree during automation in a variable. Have tried :

```
var op = target.logElementTree();
UIALogger.logMessage(op);
```

The Log result would be "null value" so I am trying to figure out on how to access that information by storing it during my execution ..

> IN SHORT " I want to store the result of target.logElementTree() which is one way of doing it I believe.

Thanks for taking your time in going through till the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logElementTree` writes to the log, and does not return a value.  The only way to get the hierarchy from within code is to recursively traverse it yourself, e.g. [visiting the `.elements()` array of each element](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator/blob/826514f7746a9e01bbee93aab1015dc97e53c09c/gem/resources/js/Extensions.js#L941-1053).